# Discord bot not sending messages to the server

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Discord API token
TOKEN = "token"

# Discord client
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

# Website URL
url = 'https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire'

# Function to fetch latest article link
def get_latest_article_link():
    # Send a GET request to the website URL
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the latest article link
    latest_article_link = soup.find('a', class_='FeaturedNews-header')['href']

    # Return the latest article link
    return latest_article_link

# Event listener for when the bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

# Command to send the latest article link to the specified channel
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!latest'):
        # Get the latest article link
        latest_article_link = get_latest_article_link()

        # Send the latest article link to the specified channel
        channel = client.get_channel("channel ID")
        await channel.send(latest_article_link)

# Run the bot
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I have created a discord bot that sends latest articles from `https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire` and sends to my specified discord channel. The code runs perfectly but not sends messages to the server.

You can see the output of that code in the attached image.

[image: Please help me to fix this!]

I was expecting the output that I want as I said before.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to include the 'message_content' intent:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Then you should be able to check the message content for the command:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!latest'):
        # Do something to handle command.
```

Comment: So I have to create another python file for this or just add it in the previous code ?

Comment: You don't need a new file. At the top of your code, you already create the client: "client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())". You can simply replace that line with my first code sample which also creates a client but expands the intents. The second code sample I wrote is the same as what you already have. It just shows where the message content can now be read.